# Usar metodo ping para guardarlo en un arreglo c# para un juego

Tags: c#

Cómo puedo almacenar todas las capturas de ping del server en un arreglo.

Lo capturo y lo muestro en un listbox y de ahí agarro el menor y mayor ping, le puse un timer para que lo haga cada segundo. El problema es que si pinta a cada segundo va a crear un bucle.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            double[] num = new double[i];

            using (Ping p = new Ping())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(p.Send("ip99.ip-144-217-175.net").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms\n");

                lblbajo.Text = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Min(x => Convert.ToString(x));
                lblalto.Text = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Max(x => Convert.ToString(x));
            }
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No me queda claro, sobre todo porque haces un clear al final. estas usando winform o wpf? y a que te refieres con que se pinta a cada rato?

Comment: No me queda claro el problema del bucle pero recuerda que la clase Timer tiene el método .Stop() para detener las ejecuciones.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos! Es bien sencillo la verdad. Lo primero es que el vector debe estar declarado fuera del ciclo, y luego cambias la asignación de los valores al vector:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] num = new double[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        using (Ping p = new Ping())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.Send("ip99.ip-144-217-175.net").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms\n");

            num[0] = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Min(x => Convert.ToString(x));
            num[1] = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Max(x => Convert.ToString(x));
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

En el caso anterior `num[0]` siempre va a representar el menor valor y `num[1]` siempre va a representar el mayor valor.

Ahora bien, ya que tu pregunta está resuelta y es un poco ambigua, planteate lo siguiente:

1. Llamar el temporizador en un hilo (`Thred`) para evitar que se
   congele el programa.
2. Usar condiciones antes de sustituir los valores del arreglo, para asegurar que los valores siempre sean los más bajos o altos.